# Hide menu, when clicking anywhere else than the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that appears when I click an icon. Currently I can close it by clicking the 'close' icon, but I would like to be able to close it by clicking anywhere outside of the menu, when the menu is visible.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/budapesti/3v5ym2bp/3/

For example the following doesn't work:

```
$(document).click(function() { 
        if($('.menu').is(":visible")) {
            $('.menu').hide()
        }      
});
```

I found similar questions, such as [jQuery: Hide element on click anywhere else apart of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720495/jquery-hide-element-on-click-anywhere-else-apart-of-the-element?lq=1) and [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element), but couldn't get the solutions to work for me.

---

EDIT: I wonder if is(":visible") works with jQuery "animate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css attribute `left` to detect if the menu is visible instead of `:visibe` because it's bot work with chrome, see **[jquery .is(“:visible”) not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome)**.

You have just to detect if the menu is visible (use the css attribute left) because if the menu css `left=0px` that mean it's visible, and after that if the `click` is outside of menu or not and so if outside close it.

Take a look at **[Your updating fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ym2bp/21/)** work fine just by adding the following `handle` that detect outside click :

**JS :**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    //if the menu is visible
    if($(".menu").css('left') =="0px"){
        //if the click is outside of menu
        if($(e.target).closest('.menu').length == 0){
            $('.closed').click();
        } 
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 3):

call close function on anywhere click on window. And use event bubbling.
i had update it its jsfiddle link is

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrchaurasia/3v5ym2bp/19/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ym2bp/13/

html

```
<div class="inv"></div><!-- Added an invisible block -->
<div class="menu"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove closed pull-right"></span>

    <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="icon-menu"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>MENU</div>
```

css

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 285px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -285px;
    background: #202024;
    z-index: 1;
}
.glyphicon-remove, ul {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Added an invisible block */
.inv {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
}
```

jQuery

```
"use strict";

var main = function () {
    $('.icon-menu').click(function () {
        $('.icon-menu').hide();
        $('.inv').show(); //added
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });
    //Added
    $('.inv').click(function () {
        $('.inv').hide();
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-285px"
        }, 200);
        $('.icon-menu').show();

    });


    $('.closed').click(function () {
        $('.inv').hide();//added
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-285px"
        }, 200);
        $('.icon-menu').show();

    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Another simple example : http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ym2bp/17/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you bind an event on document click after menu has been shown, the event that will ensure that every click anywhere outside menu will close it.

```
$(document).on("click.menu",function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);   
            if (!target.closest(".menu").length || target.closest(".closed").length) {
                closeMenu(function() {
                    $(document).off("click.menu");
                });
            }           
        });
```

here you'll have to evaluate event object, and what trigger it - which element if it's inside menu (apart from the close button) then don't do nuffing, if outside - then close the menu. All the closing stuff is put to the separate function. also don't forget to unbind this handler from document after closing

http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ym2bp/15/

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ym2bp/15/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.icon-menu').hide();
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"}, 200);
     
  });


  $('.closed').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"}, 200);
    $('.icon-menu').show();
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);


var rahul=0;
$(window).click(function(e) {
    
 $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"}, 200);
    $('.icon-menu').show();
        
   
 });
```

```css
.menu {
 position: fixed;
 width: 285px;
 height: 100%;
 left: -285px;
 background: #808080;
 z-index: 1;
}

.glyphicon-remove, ul {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove closed pull-right"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>menu1</li>
      <li>menu2</li>
      <li>menu3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="icon-menu" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>*MENUS*
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```